# FDTD simulations for metamaterials and complex refractive index

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, simulations, metamaterials

I have designed a working FDTD code to simulate electromagnetic wave propagation using Yee's algorithm. I have been able to place materials such as glass slabs, etc which have positive and real refractive indices and then look at the waves as they pass through the materials.

In an attempt to include materials with complex refractive indices, negative refractive indices (objects like metamaterials, gain materials, lossy materials, etc.), I am thinking of taking the existing code and making the variables of permittivity, permeability, electric field and magnetic field of complex type rather than double type in order to run my simulations.

Is this approach valid? Is it absolutely necessary to implement frequency dependent response for such objects? For example, if I want to simulate a left-handed metamaterial, can I do so using the method I mentioned?

Comment: This approach is correct. There is nothing in the equations that it is based on that the requires the refractive index to be real.

Comment: But is it absolutely necessary for me to implement frequency dependent response?

Comment: Not absolutely. It may well be that constant RI is a good approximation. Aren't you working with a single frequency? That is commonly done.

Comment: Can you point me toward any code that has done something similar for materials with complex refractive indices?

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. True, you can put complex index into wave-equation, but will it lead to physically reasonable solution. Depends on the algorithm. So test it. Put 1+i as your refractive index in a uniform medium, launch a wave into it and see if you will get exponential growth or decay. Another question is, in your FTDT which sign of the imaginary refractive index is loss and which is gain?

Comment: I woud think that as soon as you have real and imaginary components to the refractve index (or permittivity, or permeability etc) you have dispersion, i.e. different response at different frequencies. To account for it in a time-domain method I would expect to need to give the dispersive curve to the algorithm in some shape or form

Comment: Well, I will keep the frequency fixed.  Would I still have to account for the frequency dependent response?

Comment: Since you didn't get an answer, I thought I'd let you know that we have a tag just for TDTD here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. You're welcome to ask the question again over there if you're still looking for an answer.